# String Compression in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

I have written a piece of code that compresses Strings of non numeric characters. for example "aabccccaaa" would compress to a2b1c4a3. I was wonder if the way I am accomplishing this has an efficient asymptotic run-time. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish?

Code Provided Below:

```
public static String Compress(String s)
{
    if(s.length()<=2)
    {
        return s;
    }
    int org_length=s.length();
    String comp="";
    int i=0;
    while(i<org_length)
    {
        Integer lc=1;
        while(i+1<org_length && s.charAt(i)==s.charAt(i+1))
        {
            lc++;
            i++;

        }
        if(i>=org_length){
            comp=comp+s.charAt(s.length()-1)+1;
        }
        else{
        comp=comp+s.charAt(i)+lc.toString();
        }

        i++;
    }
    if(s.length()<=comp.length())
    {
        return s;
    }
    return comp;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify, are you asking if your run-length encoding approach is efficient, or if there is a more efficient way to compress strings?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding

Comment: I would say both but if I had to choose one it would be if there is a more efficient way to compress strings.

Comment: You might be able to use a regular expression to split the string into groups...

Comment: Thank you to both Matt Coubrough and SLaks I didn't know there was name for the way I was doing this.

Comment: If you're looking for alternative solutions, there have been a number of past discussions of compression here on Stack Exchange; searching ought to find them. 

One more efficient way to compress data when you can't predict its contents is Lempel-Ziv Markov Chain Compression.

Comment: This is called *Run Length Encoding*, it isn't new, it isn't magical and it is extremely well documented in various forms on the internet at large in great detail.

Comment: There's also http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

The while counter should compare the start-of-group character until it changes or the string end is reached. Then simply write the start-of-group character and the captured length. The complexity should be O(n).

```
public String rleCompress (String str) {
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    int len = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len;) {
       char c = str[i];
       int l = 0;
       // Always will loop at least once.
       while (i < len && str[i] == c) {
         l++;
         i++;
       }
       res.append(c);
       res.append(l);
    }
    return res.toString();
}
```

(This is a "cleaner" implementation, mainly because it isolates the boundary value, but has the same overall complexity, assuming a string concatenation is constant - hopefully it is clear that it reads through the string exactly once.)

However, [Run-Length Encoding (RLE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) is only good in very specific cases - mainly when a single value is repeated for *many* times. As in the case of the presented data it is compressed to 80%, but "ababababab" would "compress" to 200% the original!

For very short (~4+ charactes) strings [SMAZ](http://github.com/antirez/smaz/tree/master) may be appropriate: "Smaz is a simple compression library suitable for compressing very short
strings." (It is tailored to "English-like text", so it may not be suitable for this data.)

For short strings (~60+ characters), a [zlib/DEFLATE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib) implementation may be more practical. (Some DEFLATE implementations will create a useless large dictionary when not required; make sure to check the actual "compressed" size and allow for an alternate or no-compress mode.)

Comment: *but "ababababab" would "compress" to 200% the original!* demonstrates a fundamental lack of comprehension of run length encoding. There are implementations that would still compress this and compress it well to `ab5` in this case. Run length encoding isn't limited to single bytes repeated, it is a technique that lends itself to multi-byte repetitions as well, just as I have demonstrated here.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson That is a valid point - this assumes a window of a single character.